# Change currency sign oracle d2k reports?

Tags: forms, oracle, report, oracleforms, oraclereports

I want to replace $ sign to 'Rs.' in oracle d2k reports. In some system it is displaying Rs but in some system it is showing $. From where I have to change the sign.

Comment: Shouldn't you set the territory so that things like group/decimal separators and month names (if you use those) are as you expect, not just the currency symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the currency in your NLS_TERRITORY settings as follows:

```
select to_char(123456789.91, 'L999,999,999,990.00') from dual;
```

L999,999,999,990.00 is the format mask you may be able to set in the property sheet (it's a while since I used Reports) or you can use a sql function like in the example above.

Or you can take the date and format it as a string (as above) and concatenate with the character you want to display. Obviously this isn't as flexible.

```
select 'Rs'||to_char(123456789.91, '999,999,999,990.00') from dual;
```

You can check your nls_settings by connecting in sqlplus

```
SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters;
```

Comment: Thank you Kayakpim, I am using the formate mask as "LNNGNNGNNGNNGNNGNNGNN0" but the problem is even after using this few of the system are not supporting and printing $ instead of Rs. in all the reports of module.

Comment: I guess the process/connection running that report has a different NLS setting

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as well.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR
      (-10000,
       'L99G999D99MI',
       'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''
NLS_CURRENCY = ''RS'' '
      ) "Amount"
FROM DUAL;
```